# How to make sure all content appear on the cell and not just the first word?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am having a problem displaying content on a table from mysql table in the database to a form in PHP. My problem is that only the first word show on the address field for example.

Please look at my page on: http://www3.londonmet.ac.uk:8008/~iia0014/employeeManager.php

And also the cells are not aligned with the title.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

On my css I have:

```
table {
table-layout:fixed;
width:180%;
overflow:hidden;
border:1px ;
word-wrap:nowrap;
text-align:left;
}
```

But even if removing the CSS, just the first word appear.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
// Connect to server and select databse.
$con = mysql_connect("$host","$username","$password");
if (!$con){
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("$db_name",$con);

if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE employees SET 
Name='$_POST[name]', 
DOB='$_POST[dob]', 
Tel='$_POST[tel]', 
Address='$_POST[address]', 
Department='$_POST[department]',
PayRate='$_POST[payrate]', 
Skills='$_POST[skills]', 
Gender='$_POST[gender]' 
WHERE EmpNo='$_POST[hidden]'";               
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
 };


 if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM employees WHERE EmpNo='$_POST[hidden]'";          
mysql_query($DeleteQuery, $con);
};

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO employees (EmpNo, Name, DOB, Tel, Address, Department, PayRate,                   Skills, Gender) VALUES ('$_POST[uempNo]','$_POST

[uname]','$_POST[udob]', '$_POST[utel]','$_POST[uaddress]','$_POST[udepartment]',         '$_POST[upayrate]','$_POST[uskills]','$_POST[ugender]')";         
mysql_query($AddQuery, $con);
};



$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
?>

<table border="1"  width="10%">

<?php



echo "<tr>

<th>Number</th>
<th >Employee Name</th>
<th>DOB</th>
<th>Telephone</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Department</th>
<th>Pay Rate</th>
<th>Skills</th>
<th>Gender</th>
</tr>";


while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<form action=employeeManager.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['EmpNo'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=name value=" . $record['Name'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=dob value=" . $record['DOB'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=tel value=" . $record['Tel'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=address value=" . $record['Address'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=department value=" . $record['Department'] . "     </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=payrate value=" . $record['PayRate'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=skills value=" . $record['Skills'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=gender value=" . $record['Gender'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value=delete" . " </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
}
echo "<form action=employeeManager.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uempNo></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uname></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=udob></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=utel></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uaddress></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=udepartment></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=upayrate></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uskills></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=ugender></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=add value=add" . " </td></tr>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: The code is on the link.  :-) I will add now here.

Comment: php is serverside scripting! we cannot see code of php with that link though

Comment: `<td><input type=text name=address value=somewhere </td>` Well that doesn't look right. You aren't closing your `<input>` tags, and make sure to put your attributes in quotes, *especially* when the value will contain spaces.

Comment: well, thats why i said him to add his php code!

Comment: Please have a look on my code above, it does work and gets the details from the tables, but just the 1st word appears. :-(

Comment: I tried closing the input, but it became more messed up and still just the 1st word showed. The double quotes are placed correctly, u can see now that I added my php source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below quotes you were missing quotes and the tags were not closed proprely!

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    echo "<form action='employeeManager.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='hidden' name=hidden value='" . $record['EmpNo'] . "'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='name' value='" . $record['Name'] . "'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='dob' value='" . $record['DOB'] . "'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='tel' value='" . $record['Tel'] . "'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='address' value='" . $record['Address'] . "'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='department' value='" . $record['Department'] . "     </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='payrate' value='" . $record['PayRate'] . "'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='skills' value='" . $record['Skills'] . "'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='gender' value='" . $record['Gender'] . "'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='update' value='update'> </td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='delete' value='delete'> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

For better understanding of your mistake, notice your code:

```
echo "<td><input type=text></td>";
```

It should be like that:

```
echo "<td><input type='text'></td>";
```

Comment: This should definitely use HEREDOC and and `<input>` should be closed with `/>` as OP is using XHTML DOCTYPE, and the name field should be in double quotes as names can contain single quotes. WIll +1 if those are done =o)

Comment: oh man i didn't notice it :( huhuhuhuhuuhuhuhuh :/ got to change everything!

Comment: Good one, thank you, you have resolved the issue of showing all data of a cell, but as I said, it looks more messed up, not aligned. How do I proceed on this table perfection, I have been trying to make it aligned with the first row which is the title, but it doesnt seem to work. I am learning PHP by myself, sorry if I am confused. Please, have a Look on the result: http://www3.londonmet.ac.uk:8008/~iia0014/employeeManager.php

Comment: first remove `table-layout:fixed` and there is still errors in the code, please make them correct

Comment: when I do this, the table goes all over, it gets too big and goes across and past the right column:http://www3.londonmet.ac.uk:8008/~iia0014/employeeManager.php

Comment: hey remove your errors completely from php file and what you want to do now? you table is very big so, it can be changed otherwise if changed will lose it styles!

Comment: My only issue is the table going accross when I remove the table-layout:fixed as you said, but the rest works very well. :-)

Comment: add a `<br>` after Address column and check

Comment: Nothing happens with the </br>

Comment: you added </br> or <br>   ?

Comment: first <br> after </br>. It did nothing

Comment: Ok, Thank you for all effort. ;-)

Comment: your php code is still not debugged correctly! Suggesting You to debug it as i said what were your mistake and please also click the upvote arrow beside my answer floating left where there is written 1. Thanks to you for corporating with me also and accept the answer also :) increasing repo! and may you be a programming lecturer and your profile pic is good!

Comment: Mistake is just the alignment of the table. :-(

Comment: ahahahahha now you debugged php O.o

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21961/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-learnerno1)

Answer (score 1):

It works, its just that you don't close the  tag, which results in:

<input type=text name=address value=one two thre

The browser reads it as value=one and "two" and "three" like separate arguments.
What you need is a quote like this:

<input type=text name=address value="one two three"/>